# How can i crop part of a video while recording from desktop in real time using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this line to record from the desktop to a video file:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

But this will record the whole desktop.
Is there any way to record in real time only specific area/part of the desktop ?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

**#1** By specifying gdigrab options:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -video_size 960x540 -offset_x 240 -offset_y 450 -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

This captures a 960x540 video whose top-left corner is at (240,450) measured from the top-left corner of the display.

**#2** By cropping it post-capture

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 24 -i desktop -vf crop=960:540:240:450 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The former is preferable.